# UIActivityViewController only shows message and mail

Tags: ios, swift

I invoke the UIActivityViewController:

```
        var text = "Test Image"
        var actItems = [text, appDelegate.image!]

        var activityVc: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: actItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityVc.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAirDrop]
        self.presentViewController(activityVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I read on the web the reason why facebook, etc.. is missing is because I'm not logged in. However Im logged into my facebook account, also a Whatsapp account.

Comment: Are you testing on actual device? Can you try share something from other applications and check if that activity controller contains facebook, etc. If it does not, than your code is fine.